# ImageIO.write not writing image into folder

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am working on a project in which I am trying to store all the pixels of a jpg image in an array, and then using that array to write a copy of the original image in a different folder. However, I do not seem to be able to write the copy into the folder. I know that the issue has something to do with the copy of the image I created, since the writing works perfectly if I use the original image as the parameter in ImageIO.write, but i'm still not entirely sure what the issue is. Does anyone know what sort of error I may be encountering, and what I could do to fix it? (For additional context, I know that reading/writing can be implemented without using arrays, but I want to use arrays to implement this)
Code for reference:

```
package com.company;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class filereader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    int width = 1536;
    int height = 2048;
    BufferedImage image = null;
    BufferedImage newimage = null;
    int[][] newarray = new int[height][width];
    File f = null;
    File g = null;
    try {
      System.out.println("Insert your file");
      Scanner scanney = new Scanner(System.in);
      String arg1 = scanney.next();
      f = new File(arg1);  
      image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      image = ImageIO.read(f);
      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
          newarray[i][j] = image.getRGB(j, i);
        }
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error:" + e);
    }
    try {
      newimage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      System.out.println(newimage.getType());
      for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {
          int newimagestuff = newarray[i][j];
          newimage.setRGB(j, i, newimagestuff);
        }
      }
      int i = 0;
      g = new File("C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\File Reading\\Outputest.jpg");
      ImageIO.write(newimage,"jpg", g);
      System.out.println(newimage);
      System.out.println(image);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("Error:" + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: One important thing to notice, is that `ImageIO.write(..)` will return a `boolean`, indicating if the write was successful. In your case, it will return `false`. This is because the default JPEG plugin does not support images with an alpha component (RGB*A*). Instead use `TYPE_INT_RGB` and the code should work.

Comment: Finally, I'd like to point out that copying image files pixel by pixel is not efficient and will reduce quality in the case of JPEG compression. Instead, it's much faster/more efficient/better quality to just copy the file directly, without decoding. 

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- You create two new BufferedImages - the first one is completely useless as you are overwriting it in the next line with the result of `ImageIO.read()`.
- The second BufferedImage you create has the type `BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB` which is probably wrong as JPG images don't have an alpha channel (thats the "A" in the type). You rather should use the type of the `image` read in with `ImageIO`.
- Also why do you copy pixel by pixel when you could read always a complete row - if it has to be a two-dimensional array for intermediate storage - or even the complete image at once - if a single-dimensional image would suffice. You can use `public int[] getRGB​(int startX, int startY, int w, int h, int[] rgbArray, int offset, int scansize)` and the matching `setRGB` method for this.

Answer (score 0):

I think escaping the space in your file path might help. Like that:

```java
      g = new File("C:\\Users\\user1\\Documents\\File\ Reading\\Outputest.jpg");
```